# Sharepoint REST API filter empty LookUp field

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, rest, lookup-column, sharepoint-rest-api

I'd like to know how I can filter ListItems in SharePoint rest API (2013) on empty lookup. On my list items, there is a lookup (single value, not required) and i'd like to get all items where lookup is empty (blank).

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items?&select=Id&$expand=MyLookUp/Id&$filter=??
```

Does someone has a clue ? 
Thx

Answer (score 5):

Hi try giving null for value for lookup column value

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items?&select=Id&$expand=MyLookUp/Id&$filter=MyLookUp/Id eq null
```

Answer (score 3):

**REST API in SharePoint 2013 does Not support null values for filtering on list item queries**.

**However you can combine CAML query with REST API to get the required data.**

Please refer below code : 
(Note : please change your query/URL):

```
 function _rest_Post(rquest) {
        return $.ajax({
            method: rquest.method,
            url: rquest.url,
            contentType: rquest.contentType,
            headers: rquest.header,
            data: JSON.stringify(rquest.body),
        });

    }

function GetByCaml(serviceParams) {
    var req = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: url + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('" + serviceParams.create.lName + "')/getitems",
        header: {
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        body: serviceParams.create.body,
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",

    };
    return _rest_Post(req);

}

function getData(){
    var queryViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><IsNull><FieldRef Name='Project_x0020_Manager'/></IsNull></Where></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/></ViewFields></View>";
    var params = {};
    params.create= {};
    params.create.lName = "MyList";
    params.create.filter = "";
    params.create.body = {
        'query':{ 
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' },
            'ViewXml': queryViewXml
        }
    }
    return GetByCaml(params);
};


getData().then(function(data){
    //success handler
}, function(error){
    //failure handler
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + drinkTypeListName + "')/items?$select=Title,Drink/Title,Drink/Id&$expand=Drink&$filter=Drink/Title eq '" + selectedDrink + "'";
```

Ref: [Cascading drop down in SharePoint using REST API.](http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.com/2017/06/cascading-drop-down-in-sharepoint.html)

Comment: This is really close. If you want to find items where the lookup item hasn't been selected, e.g. NULL, filter on Id eq -1. For Drink, you would filter on Drink/Id eq -1. -1 is the default value SharePoint assigns to lookup columns that haven't yet been selected.